# How to wait for one second in the middle of an action

Tags: cocoa-touch, nstimer, wait

I have an action in while loop.

```
while (y < 26)
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.06 target:self selector:@selector(self) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    self.ball.center = CGPointMake(_ball.center.x + 0, _ball.center.y + 10);

    y = y + 1;
}
```

I have an image of a ball a when the button is click, I want the ball to start moving downwards, but I need it to wait for .5 seconds and then go again or it will go down instancely. I tryed `sleep(.5)` and 
    `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.05 target:self selector:@selector(self) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];`, but they did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS you don't do animations by hand (in this case you're trying to do it with a while loop). Instead, you ask the OS to do the animation for you. The following is a super simple option to achieve the ball movement you want:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

    self.ball.center = CGPointMake(self.ball.center.x + 0, self.ball.center.y + 10);
}];
```

Please replace your code (including the while loop) with the one I'm giving you here.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you may stop thread with this method but animation should/must be called on Main Thread. When you stop Main Thread then app get freeze for some time. It is bad idea to do this.

Comment: This did not work my app froze for a more than one second and then moved to the very bottom

Comment: @Programer, please see my updated answer. It will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can animate move of a ball as following:

```
/// declare block for animating
@property (nonatomic, strong) void(^animationCompletion)(BOOL);

CGFloat static kAnimationDuration = 0.3;
...

/// you declare here next position
CGPoint myPoint = CGPointMake(x, y)

/// create weak of self to not make retain cycle
ClassName __weak weakSelf = self;

/// define completion block declared above.
/// this block is called when one step is done. look below this block.
self.animationCompletion = ^(BOOL finished) {
    myPoint = CGPointMake... //next point to move to
    if (myPoint == lastPoint/*or other check when to finish moving*/) {
        weakSelf.animationCompletion = nil; /// nil your block to not call this again
    }
    /// call next animation with next step
    UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration animations:^{
        // animate to next point
    } completion:weakSelf.animationCompletion; /// and call block itself to make some sort of loop. 
}

/// here is first call of above block. you make first step here.
UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration animations:^{
 // animate to next point
} completion:self.animationCompletion;
```

Is it working? Yes. Look at Arcade Balls app for iOS. I used it there.

Comment: This was not really what I was looking for, I am only a begginer in cocoa touch and this is quite complicated for me. I just wanted the action to pause for .5 second and then go on.